# Subtract 2 dates to get number of Days

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I am working in advantage sql database, and trying to subtract 2 dates to get number of days.  I thought in ADV SQL you could just subtract the dates and it would give you the num of days.

((completed) - (startdate))

1-23-19 - 1-3-19 = 20 days

Comment: Are your date columns of the correct type or are they strings?

Comment: They are date fields

Comment: Completed is a timestamp
startdate  is a Date

Comment: I don't know anything about Advantage but it would makes sense if you first would have to convert timestamp to Date before doing the subtraction

Comment: it is the timestamp field causing the issue.  I do not know how to convert timestamp to date field in ADV sql.  Cast or convert do not work.  I am new to ADV SQL and i do not care for it

Comment: What happens if you do `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY, CONVERT(startdate, SQL_TIMESTAMP), completed)` ? or maybe with cast insted of convert, `CAST( startdate AS  SQL_TIMESTAMP)`?

Comment: I get an error message. cast(startdate was SQL_timestamp) works, but thats not what i need i need to take completed(currently a timestamp) and make that date, and that doesnt work in the example you gave me.

Comment: Are you sure about that if you want to use TIMESTAMPDIFF? Subtracting dates is probably not working

Answer (score 2):

You can directly subtract dates in ADS SQL if both are of type `DATE`. If they're both `TIMESTAMP`, you can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` with `TSI_SQL_DAYS` as the interval. If one is a `DATE` and the other a `TIMESTAMP`, you have to convert the `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE`, and then you can directly subtract.

Here are examples of all three of those alternatives.

With both columns as type `DATE`:

```
create table Test (ID integer, StartDate Date, Completed Date);
insert into Test values (1, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-31');
insert into Test values (2, '2019-01-01', '2018-02-28');
select id, startdate, completed, completed - startdate as days from test;
```

Output:

```
id  startdate    completed    days      
--- -----------  -----------  ----
1   01/01/2019   01/31/2019     30
2   01/01/2019   02/28/2019     58
```

With both columns as type `TIMESTAMP`:

```
create table Test2 (ID integer, StartDate TimeStamp, Completed TimeStamp);
insert into Test2 (ID, StartDate, Completed)
  values (1, CreateTimeStamp(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
             CreateTimeStamp(2019, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0, 1));
insert into Test2 (ID, StartDate, Completed)
  values (2, CreateTimeStamp(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
             CreateTimeStamp(2019, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0, 1));
select id, startdate, completed, 
  TimeStampDiff(SQL_TSI_DAY, StartDate, Completed) as days from test2;
```

Output:

```
id  startdate    completed    days      
--- -----------  -----------  ----
  1 01/01/2019   01/31/2019     30
  2 01/01/2019   02/28/2019     58
```

With one a `DATE` and one a `TIMESTAMP`:

```
create table Test3 (ID integer, StartDate TimeStamp, Completed Date);
insert into Test3 (ID, StartDate, Completed)
  values (1, CreateTimeStamp(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), '2019-01-31');
insert into Test3 (ID, StartDate, Completed)
  values (2, CreateTimeStamp(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), '2019-02-28');
select id, startdate, completed, 
  Completed - Cast(StartDate AS SQL_DATE) as days from test3;
```

Output:

```
id  startdate    completed    days      
--- -----------  -----------  ----
  1 01/01/2019   01/31/2019     30
  2 01/01/2019   02/28/2019     58
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `timestampdiff()` should do what you want:

```
timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_DAY, startdate, completed)
```

Comment: its not working.  im not sure if its because 1 is a timestamp and 1 is just a date?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty unusual DB to get questions on - docs suggest (https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage10/index.html?master_supported_scalar_functions.htm ) that you need :

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY,completed, startdate)`

Edit : including the cast

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY,completed, cast(startdate as SQL_TIMESTAMP))`

Docs :

> TIMESTAMPDIFF( interval, timestamp1, timestamp2 )
>
> Returns number of integer intervals based on subtracting timestamp1
>   from timestamp2. Interval values supported are: SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND,
>   SQL_TSI_SECOND, SQL_TSI_MINUTE, SQL_TSI_HOUR, SQL_TSI_DAY,
>   SQL_TSI_WEEK, SQL_TSI_MONTH, SQL_TSI_QUARTER, SQL_TSI_YEAR.

Comment: i get this error message when using your code.    [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid argument to scalar function: TIMESTAMPDIFF. Argument must be char, date, time or timestamp. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 232 (line: 6 column: 5)

Comment: The docs show `cast` is supported, so try cast(yourDateField as SQL_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2159;  [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid argument to scalar function: TIMESTAMPDIFF. Argument must be char, date, time or timestamp. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 291 (line: 7 column: 5)

Comment: @BrianK - I would be tempted to cast both sides and see what it does - its quite possible that the types are not what you expect.

Comment: @BrianK, it is PROBABLY due to your date references..  Are you dealing with actual date/time fields?  Coming from a string provided input?  if string format it should be presented in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format and not MM-dd-yy per your example